# Why using iterators this way works?

Tags: c++, stl

Here is a minimal code in order to recreate the condition that makes me doubt:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string> mm;

  mm.emplace("Hi", "asd");
  mm.emplace("Hey", "asd");
  mm.emplace("Hello", "asd");

  std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it = mm.find("Hey");
  it->second.size();

  // A
  //it->second.replace(0,1,"h");

  //B
  auto u = it->second;
  u.replace(0,1,"h");
}
```

Why is there a error of passing constant as an argument in case `A` but works in case `B` ?

Details of the error:

> error: passing 'const std::basic_string' as 'this' argument of
>   'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT,
>   _Traits, _Alloc>::replace(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator;
>   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned
>   int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: "here a error of passing constant ": Could you please post error code?

Comment: I think  you use const iterator, you cannot chane const object. In second case "auto u = it->second;" you create copy of object and call replace for it.

Comment: Case B doesn't do what I think you think it does. Print `it->second` or `mm["Hey"]` and take a look.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is quite simple: `it` is a **const** iterator, so `it->second` is a `const std::string` and you cannot call non-const method on it.

When you deal with:

```
auto u = it->second;
```

`auto` is deduced as `std::string` and `u` is initialized from `it->second`. As `u` is non-const `std::string`, you are free to call both const and non-const methods.

Comment: Lol, how does FS live?

Comment: As a side note, using `auto& u = it->second;` would behave exactly as case A

Comment: That's interesting, I thought that `auto` would automatically keep the same object type. How is it possible that `auto` doesn't keep the `const` keyword ?

Comment: Remember that changing `u` would not modify the value in the map. Where example `A` you were trying to change the value in the map.

Comment: @Deewy `auto` deduces the type of the variable from the type of the initializer. Since `auto x=3;` wouldn't make much sense to create a const integer due to the constness of the literal `3` the constness is used to deduce the type. -- But you can add the const attribute: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: @Deewy Think of it like this: `auto u = ...` works like a pass-by-value; the resulting variable holds a copy of the original one. If you want pass-by-reference semantics, you need to say so with `auto& u = ...`.

Comment: I’d recommend adding a mention that `u` is a *copy* into the answer, and that the value in the map remains the same.

Comment: @DanielH I feel it is clear enough because I say that `u` is initialized from `it->second` and `u` is a `std::string` itself...

Comment: @EdgarRokyan The reason I think emphasizing that it’s a copy is a good idea is that this is the entire reason it works. Both this question and the asker’s other questions indicate some lack of experience with C++, so explaining things more clearly is warranted. In many other languages, most types are by default references, in which case the `const`ness would need to be preserved.